# Parent process and child process relation

Tags: c#, .net, process

I have parent process that opens child process . I need to perform some functionality only when the parent process is no more running.

What is the best way to know that the parent process is not running ? Because it can be terminated violently then I don't want to make some  functionality that will send signal to my child process on the closing event.

Or just looking for my parent process like that:

In the parent make this and pass it to the child  `Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id`
And in the child every several milliseconds check this one

```
Process localById = Process.GetProcessById(1234);
```

Any ideas ? Recommendations ..

Comment: Erm... usually it's a parent process. Unless you really do recognize the gender of your process. Cheers.

Comment: @AOI Karasu: lol, good point, I took the liberty to change that (if the gender is important, please revert my changes, Night Walker).

Comment: I have just published a child process library for .NET
http://childprocess.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a simple example how to use `Process.WaitForExit` to check for a parent process whose id has been passed on the command line:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

class Program
{
    static AutoResetEvent _autoResetEvent;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int parentProcessId = int.Parse(args[0]);

        _autoResetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);

        WaitCallback callback = delegate(object processId) { CheckProcess((int)processId); };
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(callback, parentProcessId);

        _autoResetEvent.WaitOne();
    }

    static void CheckProcess(int processId)
    {
        try
        {
            Process process = Process.GetProcessById(processId);
            process.WaitForExit();
            Console.WriteLine("Process [{0}] exited.", processId);
        }
        catch (ArgumentException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Process [{0}] not running.", processId);
        }

        _autoResetEvent.Set();
    }
}
```

Using the `Process.Exited` event could be done like this:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

class Program
{
    static AutoResetEvent _autoResetEvent;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int parentProcessId = int.Parse(args[0]);
        Process process = Process.GetProcessById(parentProcessId);
        process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        process.Exited += new EventHandler(process_Exited);

        _autoResetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        _autoResetEvent.WaitOne();
    }

    static void process_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Process exit event triggered.");
        _autoResetEvent.Set();
    }
}
```

Note that in both samples the purpose of the `AutoResetEvent` is solely to prevent your main thread from exiting. In a Windows Forms application you would not need to use it as your program will be in a message loop and only exit if you close it.

Comment: I have used the Process.Exited example . Really thanks for good explanation.

Answer (score 4):

The underlying Win32 process handle is waitable, and will be signalled when the process exits.

In native code:

```
DWORD res = WaitForSIngleObject(hProcess, INFINITE);
if (res == WAIT_OBJECT_0) {
  // process has exited.
}
```

In native code, you'll need to either create a custom subtype of [`WaitHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.waithandle.aspx) for process handles, or use P/Invoke. The disadvantage of P/Invoke is that it is harder to combine (using [`WaitForMultipleObjects`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687025(VS.85).aspx) multiple waits, so you are not dedicating a thread just to wait on one thing).

---

Thanks to [0xA3](https://stackoverflow.com/users/40347/0xa3): Just use [`Process.WaitForExit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexit.aspx) (there is an overload with a timeout to avoid indefinite waits, and don't do this on your UI thread).

Comment: Sorry not really want going to Native Code .

Comment: @Night Walker: No need to do so, simply use `Process.WaitForExit`. probably best in a separate thread.

Comment: But i need to wait in the child process for the father process. Not sure how Process.WaitForExit can help.

Comment: @NightWalker: Either the parent process passes the child process the parent process's id (e.g. on command line), or use WMI and Win32_Process request for the child's process and use the parent process id property. Once you have the parent process's id you can get a Process instance with `Process.GetProcessById()`.

Answer (score 1):

When the parent process starts the child process, pass the parents process ID to the child via command line arguments.

Then on the child process, use the `Process.GetProcessById(int)` to get the parent process and use `Process.WaitForExit()`. Alternatively, you use the `Process.Exited` event to get a notification when the parent process exits (remember to set `Process.EnableRaisingEvents` to `true`, otherwise the event will not be raised).

Answer (score 0):

I've made a child process management library where the parent process and the child process are monitored due a bidirectional WCF pipe. If either the child process terminates or the parent process terminates each other is notified.
There is also a debugger helper available which automatically attaches the VS debugger to the started child process.

The bidirectional WCF channel is extendable and you can handle process start and process terminate events.

Project site:

http://www.crawler-lib.net/child-processes

NuGet Packages:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/ChildProcesses
https://www.nuget.org/packages/ChildProcesses.VisualStudioDebug/